# How do I develop a package with an apex:map component?

Tags: visualforce

[Per the docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_maps.htm), "Visualforce mapping components aren’t available in Developer Edition organizations". This is unfortunate if you're trying to develop a package in a dev org. Is there a way to create a Visualforce Map in a Dev Org that when deployed to an EE org, it will display?

Answer (score 0):

This component is only available for customers, the license agreement with Google doesn't allow it for ISVs/package use.